# Thread-local object pooling

Tags: java, concurrency

Going through the Goetz "Java Concurrency in Practice" book, he makes a case against using object pooling (section 11.4.7) - main arguments:

1) allocation in Java is faster than C's malloc
2) threads requesting objects from a pool require costly synchronization

My problem is not so much that allocation is slow, but that periodic garbage collection introduces outliers in response time that could be eliminated by reducing object pools.

Are there any issues that I am not seeing in using this approach?  Essentially I am partitioning an object pool across the threads...

Comment: note that (JVM implementation depending) not every object ends up on the heap (where it will require garbage collection); under the right conditions, they may end up on the stack (see Escape Analysis).

Comment: @McDowell, I certain would love to see Escape Analysis kick in, but so far in my tests(Hotspot 1.6) it only seems to show promise in micro-benchmarks.

Comment: You'll get answers that are much more useful if you describe your environment and current problem rather than your approach to solving that problem. Your comment about GC outliers indicates to me that you're either using a huge number of objects with long lifetimes or huge objects. In either case, a per-thread pool is probably the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2):

If its thread local then you can forget about this:

> 2) threads requesting objects from a pool require costly synchronization

Being thread-local you need not worry about synchronization to retrieve from the pool itself.

Comment: Doesn't the "Concurrency" part of the book title suggest that it is about multi-threading?

Comment: Who says hes not multi-threading?  What if each thread pool has its own Thread specific set of data that is irrelevant to other threads?

Comment: @luiscubal: thread-local doesn't mean non-multi-threading; it means a pool for each thread.  since it's private to the thread, it doesn't need to synchronize with other threads to pick an object form it's own pool.

Comment: @Javier @John V: If it is thread-local then it can be thread-unsafe, so I'm guessing there'd be little need for concurrent-specific algorithms(as common old programming is just fine), so I don't see how the book reference would even be relevant.

Comment: @luiscubal can you explain how a thread-local object is thread-unsafe?

Comment: @John V. The effort of making something thread-local thread-safe is, the way I see it, useless. Then again, maybe the correct wording for this case is that thread-local is automatically thread-safe.

Comment: @luiscubal Thatch exactly it, you wouldn't make something thread-local thread safe because its inherently thread-safe.  But making the pool thread-local isn't useless in this case.  The synchronization is also for memory visibility.  If there are definitely threads changing the objects in the pool, then a synchronization point needs to be in place to ensure all threads see up-to-date values.  I guess my point is, if its thread-local he does not need to worry about goetz's second point

Answer (score 2):

In Java 1.4, object allocation was relatively expensive so Object pools for even simple objects could help.  However, in Java 5.0, Object allocation was significantly improved, however synchronization still had a way to go meaning that object allocation was faster than synchronization. i.e. removing object pools improved performance in many cases. In Java 6, synchronization has improved to the point where an object pool can make a little difference to performance in simple cases.

Avoiding simple object pools is a good idea because it is simpler, not for performance reasons.

For more complex/larger objects, object pools can be useful in Java 6, even if you use synchronization. e.g. a Socket, File stream, or Database connection.

Answer (score 2):

(sun's) GC scans live objects. the assumption is that there are way more dead objects than live objects in a typical java program runtime. it marks live objects, and dispose the rest.

if you cache a lot of objects, they are all live. and if you have several GBs of such objects, GC is going to waste a lot of time scanning them in vain. long GC pauses can paralyze your application.

cache something just to make it non-garbage is not helping GC.

that's not to say caching is wrong. if you have 15G memory, and your database is 10G, why not cache everything in memory, so responses are lighting fast. note this is to cache something that would otherwise be slow to fetch.

to prevent GC from fruitlessly scanning the 10G cache, the cache must be outside GC's control. For example, use 'memcached" which lives in another process, and has its own cache-optimized GC.

the latest news is Terracotta's BigMemory which is a pure java solution that does similar thing.

---

an example of thread local pooling is sun's direct ByteBuffer pooling. when we call

```
channel.read(byteBuffer)
```

if byteBuffer is  not "direct", a "direct" one must be allocated under the hood, used to communicate data with OS. in a network application, such allocations  could be very frequent, it seems to be a waste, to discard a just allocated one, and immediately allocate another one in the next statement. sun's engineers, apparently don't trust GC that much, created a thread local pool of "direct" ByteBuffers.

Comment: *created a thread local pool of "direct" ByteBuffers* ...and totally screwed the impl. in case of a large heap-buffer is attempted to be written (allocates as large DirectBuffer, copies everything but the socket buffer doesn't hold [2m+ data] and the process is repeated multiple times). The main issue w/ direct buffer is not the GC, itself; it does the job done but a very tiny java object holds tons of memory and there is no telling it should be fastly reclaimed. Also allocating (and releasing) a direct ByteBuffer requires global lock (+malloc, free).

Comment: there's no particular reason why direct BB cannot be managed within VM. then there would be no distinction of heap/direct BB and we wouldn't need to worry about cost of new/GC. Unfortunately, there is this special direct BB with extra cost. we are supposed to use them for special purposes. yet the IO impl needs plenty of small direct BB frequently. To solve this conflict, we can allocate one huge direct BB, and use little slices of it. That means we need to implement a memory management system, on top of Java platform. that is just really idiotic.

Comment: the memory address of a direct buffer cannot be relocated while heap ones can, i.e. the address is pinned as long as the buffer is alive. The address can be used by native/kernel any time, so JVM has no control over. Btw, I never needed small ByteBuffers, I usually use one direct buffer per thread and if the message doesn't fit within, the unparsed leftover gets buffered into  a heap bytebuffer or just byte[]. Almost always the messages can be delivered as a single packet or wholly parsed, so that works pretty ok in the common case. Writing state machines for parsing is considered 'hard', tho

Comment: yes the problem is alleviated in typical usage where fixed size buffers are needed and they are released quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case is reasonable situation to use pooling. There is no evil in pooling, Goetz means that you should not use it when it is not necessary. Another example is connection pooling, because creation of connection is very expensive.

Comment: There is so much truth in @Tom 's words.

Answer (score 0):

If it is threadlocal, it's very likely you may not even need pooling. Of course it would depend on the use cases, but the chances are, on a given thread you will likely need only one object of that type at a given time.

The caveat with threadlocals, however, is memory management. Note that threadlocal values don't go away easily until the thread that owns those threadlocals go away. Therefore, if you have a large number of threads and a large number of threadlocals, they may contribute to used memory quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely try it out. Although is now "common knowledge" that one should not care about object creation, in fact there may be a lot of performance gained from using object pools and specific classes. For a file processing framework, I gained 5% read performance from pooling object[] objects.

So try it out and time your executions to see if you gain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Even it's an old question, point of 2 *threads requesting objects from a pool require costly synchronization* does not completely hold true.

It's possible to write a concurrent (no synchronization) object pool that doesn't even exhibit sharing (even false sharing) on the fast path. In the simplistic case, of course, each thread might have its own pool (more like an associated object) but then such a greedy  approach can lead to resource waste (or starvation/error if the resource cannot be allocated)

Pools are good for heavy objects like ByteBuffers, esp. direct ones, connections, sockets, threads, etc. Overall any objects that require non-java intervention.